# How to get Customized template fields from invoice using QuickBooks QBFC

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I want to  get custom S.O. Invoice Template fields using QuickBooks QBFC.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to read custom fields from a sales order:

1. Add "0" to the `OwnerIDList` of the `SalesOrderQuery`.
2. Read custom header fields from the `DataExtRetList` that is attached to `SalesOrderRet` objects that are returned from the query.
3. Read custom line item fields from the `DataExtRetList` in the `SalesOrderLineRet` and `SalesOrderLineGrouptRet` objects that are included in each `SalesOrderRet` (if you're reading line items).

If you're already using the `IncludeRetElementList`, you must add `DataExtRet` to the list; if you're not then don't start using `IncludeRetElementList` until you have custom fields working. Just like any transaction query, you won't see any line item data unless you set the `IncludeLineItems` flag in the request.

Custom fields are well documented in [the QuickBooks SDK Manual](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/develop/tutorials/data-extensions-custom-fields-and-private-data). I'd recommend you take a look at the section *DataExt: Using Custom Fields and Private Data* in the *QBSDK Programmers Guide*.

Comment: sdk link broken

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Paul Keister's answer, the reason you must add "0" to the query is because that is the Owner ID of the custom field you are attempting to retrieve. 0 is probably likely to be the value, but if the owner ID is different, you will have to use a different value here.

Some example C# code:

```
//set the owner id of the custom field you are trying to get back
IInvoiceQuery invoiceQuery = requestMsgSet.AppendInvoiceQueryRq();
invoiceQuery.OwnerIDList.Add("0");

//set up query parameters and actually call your query...

//call this method for each invoice to get its custom fields (if they exist)
static void GetInvoiceCustomFields(IInvoiceRet invoice)
    {
        if (invoice.DataExtRetList == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < invoice.DataExtRetList.Count; i++)
        {
            IDataExtRet extData = invoice.DataExtRetList.GetAt(i);
            Console.WriteLine("external data name: " + extData.DataExtName.GetValue());
            Console.WriteLine("external data value: " + extData.DataExtValue.GetValue());
        }
    }
```